# Invalid `prisma.comment.create()` invocation:

Tags: prisma-graphql

When the `createComment` Mutation was excuted, an error called `Invalid 'prisma.comment.create()' invocation:`

I don't know what's wrong with this right now.

I use OSX and postgresql

schema.prisma

```
model User {
  userId             Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  fullName           String
  username           String          @unique
  avatar             String?
  email              String          @unique
  password           String
  phoneNumber        String          @unique
  location           String?
  searchHistoryOnOff Boolean         @default(true)
  notificationOnOff  Boolean         @default(true)
  notifications      Notification[]
  searchHistories    SearchHistory[]
  products           Product[]
  comments           Comment[]
  createdAt          DateTime        @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime        @updatedAt
}

model Product {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  authorId  Int
  title     String
  price     Int
  picture   String[]
  content   String?
  hits      Int       @default(0)
  author    User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [userId])
  hashtags  Hashtag[]
  comments  Comment[]
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updated
}

model Comment {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  authorId  Int
  productId Int
  comment   String
  author    User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [userId])
  product   Product  @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

typeDefs

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export default gql`
  type Mutation {
    createComment(productId: Int!, commment: String!): MutationResponse!
  }
`;
```

resolvers

```
import { Comment } from '@prisma/client';
import { protectedResolver } from '../../users/user.utils';
import { Identity, Resolvers } from './../../types.d';

const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    createComment: protectedResolver(
      async (_, { productId, comment }, { loggedInUser, client }) => {
        const { userId } = loggedInUser;
        const product: Identity = await client.product.findUnique({
          where: { id: productId },
          select: { id: true },
        });

        if (!product) {
          return {
            ok: false,
            error: '게시글이 존재하지 않음',
          };
        }

        const newComment: Comment = await client.comment.create({
          data: {
            comment,
            author: {
              connect: { userId },
            },
            product: {
              connect: { id: productId },
            },
          },
        });
        return { ok: true };
      }
    ),
  },
};

export default resolvers;
```

Please help me

Comment: What do the logs say if you create your `PrismaClient` with the options `log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error']`?